# How to pass component name dynamically in Lightning App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura

I creating a app in which each component have a button when click on the button the component should be rendered in the Lightning app page

but while calling the component from app i am not able to give the component name dynamically

```
  <aura:application controller="UniversalComponentClass" extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="components" type="AuraDefinitionBundle[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="componentname" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <lightning:layout>
            <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.components}" var="a">
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
                        <td><button type="button" onclick="{!c.showCaseDeleteModal}" label="{!a.MasterLabel}">{!a.MasterLabel}</button></td> 

                    </table>   
                </aura:iteration>
                </div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small">
            <c:{v.componentname}/>
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
</aura:application>
```

**Controller.js**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action=component.get("c.getAllComponents");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            if(state=='SUCCESS')
            {
                component.set("v.components",response.getReturnValue());
                console.log(component.get("v.components"));
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    showCaseDeleteModal:function(component,event,helper)
    {
        var ss=event.target.label;
        component.set("v.componentname",ss);
    }
})
```

is there any way to pass component name dynamically to ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the component dynamically, that is by using `$A.createComponent()` method. As per [SF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm):

> The $A.createComponent() and $A.createComponents() methods support
>   both client-side (synchronous) and server-side (asynchronous)
>   component creation. For performance and other reasons, client-side
>   creation is preferred.
>
> To use $A.createComponent(), we need the component definition. If we
>   don’t have the definition already on the client, the framework makes a
>   server trip to get it. You can avoid this server trip by adding an
>    tag for the component you’re creating in the markup
>   of the component that calls $A.createComponent(). The tag ensures that
>   the component definition is always available on the client. The
>   tradeoff is that the definition is always downloaded instead of only
>   when it’s needed. This performance tradeoff decision should depend on
>   your use case.
>
> If no server-side dependencies are found, the methods are executed
>   synchronously on the client-side. The top-level component determines
>   whether a server request is necessary for component creation. A
>   component with server-side dependencies must be created on the server.
>   Server-side dependencies include component definitions or dynamically
>   loaded labels that aren’t already on the client, and other elements
>   that can’t be predetermined by static markup analysis.

**So your code can be slightly modified to achieve such:**

```
<lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" aura:id="componentContainer">
     <!-- <c:{v.componentname}/> -->
</lightning:layoutItem>
```

**Revised showCaseDeleteModal() to create the component dynamically:**

```
showCaseDeleteModal:function(component,event,helper)
{
    var ss=event.target.label;
    $A.createComponent(
               "c:" + ss, //assuming "ss" contains the correct component name
                {}, //args - attribute keypairs that you may want to pass
                function(newComponent, status, error) {
                   if (status==="SUCCESS") {
                       var container = cmp.find("componentContainer");
                       var body = container.get("v.body");
                       body.push(newComponent);
                       container.set("v.body", body);
                   }
                }
     );
}
```

Take note of the "componentContainer"

Comment: +1 Note, though, that $A.createComponent is deprecated. $A.createComponents should be used instead.